# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'debug'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have tried to search this but to no avail. The code i have was supplied by a real nice guy on the site and then I modded the attributes to make the elements i had fit into where they needed to go, however, everything works fine in all browsers, that is, except IE - pretty much all versions. i ran the debug in IE9 and was given this error "

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'debug'

The section of code that it refers to is this

```
function resizeContent() {
    // Retrieve the window width
    var viewPortWidth = $(document).width();
    var viewPortHeight = $(document).height();

    $(".content").each(function(index, element) {

        var jElement = $(this);
        if (jElement.hasClass(currentContentColor)) {
            console.debug('resize content selected (' + (viewPortWidth - 160) + ')');
            // If current content, juste resize the width and height
            jElement.css({
                width: (viewPortWidth - 160) + "px",
                height: viewPortHeight + "px"
            });
        }
        else {
            console.debug('resize content (' + (viewPortWidth - 160) + ')');
            // If not current content, resize with, height and left position
            // (keep content outside)
            jElement.css({
                width: (viewPortWidth - 160) + "px",
                left: viewPortWidth + "px",
                height: viewPortHeight + "px"
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The Specific line in question is

```
console.debug('resize content (' + (viewPortWidth - 160) + ')');
```

Or at least that's what IE says is the issue

Is there a work around for this issue and IE - i am learning slowly - but this is way beyond anything i know. I have searched google and on here for the debug error but couldn't find anything.

The site is http://www.crazyedits.co.uk

Thank you in advance for any help you can give on this issue.

Comment: I think you can comment that line out because it's just for your information or just instead of console.debug you could use console.log

Comment: ^^ yep that worked. I really need to get my head around js and fast - I feel like my site is being built by all you guys instead of myself :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console), `console.debug` has been deprecated; `console.log` should be used instead.

> An alias for log(); this was added to improve compatibility with existing sites already using debug(). However, you should use console.log() instead.

In any case, `debug` and `log` are just for printing debugging information to the console - they should be removed from production code.

Comment: Moz. docs since updated (as of Feb 2019) to read:  "Outputs a message to the console with the log level "debug"."